postgres function execution failed after 5-6 execution repeatedly
SELECT * 
FROM public.admin_get_sales_data(1, 5000,
                                 null, null, null, null,
                                 null, null, null)

Calling this function with different first argument 1,2,3.... it fails on 5 or 6 any random execution. What is the reason and solution for this problem?
Error message after a long execution of query on 5th attempt:
ERROR:  canceling statement due to conflict with recovery
DETAIL:  User query might have needed to see row versions that must be removed.

This is the function body :
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.admin_get_sales_data(
    page_num integer,
    page_size integer,
    filter_market_id integer,
    filter_partner_id integer,
    filter_order_rating integer[],
    filter_display_id_pattern text,
    filter_date_range text,
    start_date timestamp with time zone,
    end_date timestamp with time zone)
    RETURNS TABLE(id integer, display_id character, customer_name text, partner_name character varying, partner_id integer, total_amount numeric, created_at timestamp with time zone, updated_at timestamp with time zone, items text, market_id integer, market_name character varying, order_status character varying, order_rating smallint, review text, bag_created_times timestamp without time zone[], surplus_discount_percentage numeric, deal_discount_percentage numeric, timezone_name character varying) 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
    ROWS 1000

AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    WITH bag_counts AS (
        SELECT
            bl.partner_id,
            bl.order_id,
            bl.bag_type,
            bl.bag_price,
            bl.retail_price,
            COUNT(*) AS bag_count
        FROM
            bags_listing bl
        GROUP BY
            bl.partner_id,
            bl.order_id,
            bl.bag_type,
            bl.bag_price,
            bl.retail_price
    ),
    cancelled_bag_counts AS (
        SELECT
            bl.partner_id,
            clbl.order_id,
            bl.bag_type,
            bl.bag_price,
            bl.retail_price,
            COUNT(*) AS bag_count
        FROM
            bags_listing bl
        JOIN cancelled_order_bags_listing_map clbl ON bl.id = clbl.bag_listing_id
        GROUP BY
            bl.partner_id,
            clbl.order_id,
            bl.bag_type,
            bl.bag_price,
            bl.retail_price
    )
    SELECT
        od.id,
        od.display_id,
        CONCAT(cust.first_name, ' ', cust.last_name) AS customer_name,
        pt.shop_name AS partner_name,
        pt.id AS partner_id,
        od.total_amount AS total_amount,
        od.created_at,
        od.updated_at,
        CASE
            WHEN od.order_status = 'CANCELLED' THEN (
                CASE
                    WHEN COALESCE(cbc_big.bag_count, 0) > 0 THEN CONCAT(COALESCE(cbc_big.bag_count, 0), 'x Big bag')
                    ELSE ''
                END || 
                CASE
                    WHEN COALESCE(cbc_small.bag_count, 0) > 0 THEN CONCAT(CASE WHEN COALESCE(cbc_big.bag_count, 0) > 0 THEN ', ' ELSE '' END, COALESCE(cbc_small.bag_count, 0), 'x Small bag')
                    ELSE '' 
                END || 
                CASE
                     WHEN COALESCE(cbc_deal.bag_count, 0) > 0 THEN CONCAT(CASE WHEN COALESCE(cbc_big.bag_count, 0) > 0 OR COALESCE(cbc_small.bag_count, 0) > 0 THEN ', ' ELSE '' END, COALESCE(cbc_deal.bag_count, 0), 'x Deal bag')
                     WHEN cbc_big.bag_count IS NOT NULL THEN ''
                     WHEN cbc_small.bag_count IS NOT NULL THEN ''
                     ELSE 'NA'
                END
            )
            ELSE (
                CASE
                    WHEN COALESCE(bc_big.bag_count, 0) > 0 THEN CONCAT(COALESCE(bc_big.bag_count, 0), 'x Big bag')
                    ELSE ''
                END || 
                CASE
                    WHEN COALESCE(bc_small.bag_count, 0) > 0 THEN CONCAT(CASE WHEN COALESCE(bc_big.bag_count, 0) > 0 THEN ', ' ELSE '' END, COALESCE(bc_small.bag_count, 0), 'x Small bag')
                    ELSE '' 
                END || 
                CASE
                     WHEN COALESCE(bc_deal.bag_count, 0) > 0 THEN CONCAT(CASE WHEN COALESCE(bc_big.bag_count, 0) > 0 OR COALESCE(bc_small.bag_count, 0) > 0 THEN ', ' ELSE '' END, COALESCE(bc_deal.bag_count, 0), 'x Deal bag')
                     WHEN bc_big.bag_count IS NOT NULL THEN ''
                     WHEN bc_small.bag_count IS NOT NULL THEN ''
                     ELSE 'NA'
                END
            )
        END AS items,
        pt.market_id AS market_id,
        mt.market_name,
        od.order_status,
        pr.rating AS order_rating,
        pr.comment AS review, 
        CASE
            WHEN od.order_status = 'CANCELLED' THEN (
                SELECT ARRAY(
                    SELECT 
                        CASE 
                            WHEN pt.utc_minutes_offset IS NOT NULL 
                            THEN bl.created_at AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' + INTERVAL '1 minute' * pt.utc_minutes_offset 
                            ELSE bl.created_at::timestamp without time zone
                        END
                    FROM bags_listing bl
                    JOIN cancelled_order_bags_listing_map clbl ON bl.id = clbl.bag_listing_id
                    WHERE clbl.order_id = od.id
                    ORDER BY bl.created_at
                )
            )
            ELSE (
                SELECT ARRAY(
                    SELECT 
                        CASE 
                            WHEN pt.utc_minutes_offset IS NOT NULL 
                            THEN bl.created_at AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' + INTERVAL '1 minute' * pt.utc_minutes_offset 
                            ELSE bl.created_at::timestamp without time zone
                        END
                    FROM bags_listing bl
                    WHERE bl.order_id = od.id
                    ORDER BY bl.created_at
                )
            )
        END AS bag_created_times,
        CASE  
            WHEN COALESCE(bc_big.bag_count, 0) > 0 
              OR COALESCE(cbc_big.bag_count, 0) > 0 
              OR COALESCE(bc_small.bag_count, 0) > 0 
              OR COALESCE(cbc_small.bag_count, 0) > 0 
            THEN 66.67 
            ELSE 0.00 
        END AS surplus_discount_percentage,
        CASE
            WHEN COALESCE(bc_deal.bag_count, 0) > 0 OR COALESCE(cbc_deal.bag_count, 0) > 0 THEN
                ROUND(
                    (
                        GREATEST(COALESCE(bc_deal.retail_price, 0), COALESCE(cbc_deal.retail_price, 0)) - 
                        GREATEST(COALESCE(bc_deal.bag_price, 0), COALESCE(cbc_deal.bag_price, 0))
                    ) / 
                    GREATEST(COALESCE(bc_deal.retail_price, 0), COALESCE(cbc_deal.retail_price, 0)) * 100,
                    2
                )
            ELSE
                0.00
        END AS deal_discount_percentage,
        pt.timezone_name 
    FROM
        public.orders od
    JOIN 
        public.customers cust ON od.customer_id = cust.id
    JOIN 
        public.partners pt ON od.partner_id = pt.id
    LEFT JOIN bag_counts bc_big ON od.partner_id = bc_big.partner_id AND od.id = bc_big.order_id AND bc_big.bag_type = 1
    LEFT JOIN bag_counts bc_small ON od.partner_id = bc_small.partner_id AND od.id = bc_small.order_id AND bc_small.bag_type = 2
    LEFT JOIN bag_counts bc_deal ON od.partner_id = bc_deal.partner_id AND od.id = bc_deal.order_id AND bc_deal.bag_type = 3
    LEFT JOIN cancelled_bag_counts cbc_big ON od.partner_id = cbc_big.partner_id AND od.id = cbc_big.order_id AND cbc_big.bag_type = 1
    LEFT JOIN cancelled_bag_counts cbc_small ON od.partner_id = cbc_small.partner_id AND od.id = cbc_small.order_id AND cbc_small.bag_type = 2
    LEFT JOIN cancelled_bag_counts cbc_deal ON od.partner_id = cbc_deal.partner_id AND od.id = cbc_deal.order_id AND cbc_deal.bag_type = 3
    JOIN 
        markets mt ON pt.market_id = mt.id
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            order_id,
            rating,
            comment
        FROM
            partner_ratings
        GROUP BY
            order_id,
            rating,
            comment
    ) pr ON od.id = pr.order_id
    WHERE
        od.order_status IN ('COMPLETED', 'CONFIRMED', 'CANCELLED', 'REFUNDED')
        AND (filter_market_id IS NULL OR pt.market_id = filter_market_id)
        AND (filter_partner_id IS NULL OR pt.id = filter_partner_id)
        AND (filter_display_id_pattern IS NULL OR od.display_id ILIKE '%' || filter_display_id_pattern || '%') -- Apply the display_id filter
        AND (
            CASE
                WHEN filter_date_range = 'All Time' THEN true
                WHEN filter_date_range = 'This Month' THEN DATE_TRUNC('month', od.created_at) = DATE_TRUNC('month', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
                WHEN filter_date_range = 'Today' THEN od.created_at::date = CURRENT_DATE
                WHEN filter_date_range = 'Custom' THEN od.created_at BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
                ELSE true
            END
        )
        -- Apply the filter_order_rating
        AND (filter_order_rating IS NULL OR pr.rating = ANY(filter_order_rating))
    ORDER BY
        od.created_at DESC
    LIMIT
        page_size
    OFFSET
        (page_num - 1) * page_size;
END;
$BODY$;

We need to fix this issue in this function

The error message indicates that something is wrong while running this query on the read replica. This could happen when theplica is not configured to support long- query takes too long and the rerunning queries.

I think there should have been more to the error message than just what you reported. What is the full error message?  Look in the server log to see if it included more details than what was sent to the client.

aws server logs giving error :
2024-10-23 12:56:32 UTC:106.219.161.123(21644):data_reader@goodiebag-prod:[23894]:ERROR: canceling statement due to conflict with recovery
2024-10-23 12:56:32 UTC:106.219.161.123(21644):data_reader@goodiebag-prod:[23894]:DETAIL: User query might have needed to see row versions that must be removed

You could give a longer grace period to the query by increasing max_standby_streaming_delay.  There are consequences to this which you may or may not find acceptable. You could also look into hot_standby_feedback.
If there is no good reason why the query should be slow in the first place, then you can instead just try to make it faster so it doesn't run afoul of these delays. Take the query out of the function and execute it with EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) to see why it is slow.  If it predictably happen after a certain number of executions, then maybe plan_cache_mode = force_custom_plan would help, but you also said randomly, so who knows.
Finally, you could just the query on the master, not on the replica.

PERFORM set_config('plan_cache_mode', 'force_custom_plan', true);
Worked for me thanks @jjanes
